# How to build a .NET website using Nant

Tags: .net, asp.net, msbuild, nant, csc

I usually use web applications in Visual Studio and the MSBUILD taks in Nant builds them without any problems:

```
<msbuild project="MySolution.sln">
  arg value="/property:Configuration=release" />
</msbuild>
```

I now have a website (not a web application) in a VS Solution and it won't build - I get a lot of namespace errors.

Should I be able to build the solution with MSBUILD even though it contains a website? Or do I need to use CSC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using the **devenv.exe** command if **msbuild.exe** is failing for you. Also you may be interested in [Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en).

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Answer (score 1):

In your MSBuild arguments use the OutDir option to set an output directory.  You then get the following:

1. All the DLLs in your project.
2. A directory called _PublishedWebsite.  This gives you the same output a Publish command in Visual Studio.

This is what we do to build our web apps through MSBuild.

Answer (score 1):

```
devenv.exe /rebuild debug mywebsite.sln
```

I found I had to use debug rather than release or the build was skipped.