# Compile WebSite Project with NAnt

Tags: msbuild, nant

I have a website project in Visual Studio 2008. I would like to build this website using MSBuild. I use the following command to build the solution:

msbuild.exe mysolution.sln /t:Rebuild /v:q

After I ran the command, it creates a new folder called precompiled, creates a copy of my project, removes all code files and places 1000 dll files in the bin folder.

Now when I do a "rebuild" from Visual studio, it doesn't do that.

Is there a way to rebuild the project without having it to create the precompiled folder?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're using Nant.  Might want to edit the question.

Comment: um... Why doesnt it sound like that? I am running the Nant commnd from the command line? Though I am pretty new to nant.

Comment: I think I found it. I should be using devenv.exe instead?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147437/how-to-build-a-net-website-using-nant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found it. I should be using devenv.exe instead? [How to build a .NET website using Nant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147437/how-to-build-a-net-website-using-nant)